# AbstractUser and UserChangeForm Meta Options Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to create a Django form that would allow me to include the image field when creating a AbstractUser.

```
## models.py
class Student(AbstractUser):

    def __unicode__(self):
        string = self.get_full_name()
        return unicode(string)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')

## admin.py
class StudentChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student



class StudentCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            Student.objects.get(username=username)
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
```

Despite adding the meta class that is supposedly going to create the extra fields for the form, it appears to be excluding the photo field. I have tried fields = ['photo'] that did not work at all. I understand that the UserChangeForm inherits all the changing abilities from user, but how am I supposed to add the photo image field as apart of that the change form and the creation form?